# Pre-requests from browser destroy OAuth token cookies

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, oauth, oauth-2.0

I use OAuth to authenticate against a `site A` with my `site B`. If authentication is successful I retrieve an access and a refresh token from `site A` and store them as a cookie in `site B`. This works great so far **BUT** there's a problem:

If a user enters the URL of the site into the address field of any browser. The browser sends already a request to the `site B` whose access token is outdated and so requests `site A` for a new access and refresh token. But if the answer of `site B` is pending and the user fires another request to site A then `site A` holds the old access and the outdated refresh token. But `site B` has already issued a new access and refresh token which were never delivered to the client. Because of simultaneous requests.

How should I treat this case? Because the user is at this moment locked out and has to login again (on `site A`) to get in synch again with the OAuth provider (`site B`).